# Error adding an object to a field list Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Sorry if I don't respect the conventions, I'm new here.

I have a problem in my learning of ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework.

I have bets and users that can have multiple bets. The bets can have no users (they are just displayed on the site and users add them to their account).

Here are my two models :

Bets :

```
public class Bets
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public double team1 { get; set; }
    public double team2 { get; set; }
    public string sport { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; } // 1 = yes 2 = no
    public virtual User user {get;set;}
    public int? UserId {get;set;}
}
```

User :

```
public class User    
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public double moneyBalance { get; set; }
    public int admin { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bets> bets {get; set;}
}
```

Then I tried to add a bet that already existed to a user:

```
 public async Task<bool> addUserBet(int id, Bets bet)
 {
     var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserId == id);

     if (!(user.bets == bet)) 
     {
         user.bets.Add(bet);
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
         return true;
     }

     return false;
}
```

The controller :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPut("addBetUser/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddBetUser(int id, BetForAddToUserDto betForAddTo)
{
    Bets bets = new Bets();

    _mapper.Map(betForAddTo, bets);

    await _repo.addUserBet(id, bets);
    await _repo.SaveAll();
    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

But I get this error in Postman when I try the endpoint above:

[image]

What am I doing wrong that I don't understand? Please help me, thank you :)

Comment: Could you share which line you makes error?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to add a bet that already existed to a user

If you have existed a bet and a user.And you want to add this bet to the user.

Here is a working demo like below:

1.Model:

```
public class Bets
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public double team1 { get; set; }
    public double team2 { get; set; }
    public string sport { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; } // 1 = yes 2 = no
    public virtual User user { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public double moneyBalance { get; set; }
    public int admin { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Bets> bets { get; set; }

}
public class BetForAddToUserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public double team1 { get; set; }
    public double team2 { get; set; }
    public string sport { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; } // 1 = yes 2 = no
    public virtual User user { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
}
```

2.Controller:

```
public async Task<bool> addUserBet(int id, Bets bet)
{
    var user = await _context.User.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserId == id);
    if (!(user.bets == bet))
    {
        bet.UserId = id;
        _context.Bets.Update(bet);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPut("addBetUser/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutUser(int id, BetForAddToUserDto betForAddTo)
{
    Bets bets = new Bets();           
    _mapper.Map(betForAddTo, bets);
    var bet = _context.Bets.Find(bets.Id);
    await addUserBet(id, bet);
    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

3.Profile:

```
public class AutoMapping: Profile
{
    public AutoMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<Bets, BetForAddToUserDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

4.Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapping));
}
```

Comment: Which parameter should I pass to postman to test your solution ? thank you in advance.

Comment: Just using what you posted.Be sure that you have existing user and bets.What you did is to add the user to bets.Because user and bets is one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if (!(user.bets == bet))
```

User.bets is a collection, you cannot compare it to a single bet

The right way to check it would be:

```
if (!(user.bets.Any(b => b.ID == bet.ID)))
```

Also you are not passing in anything for this parameter:

```
BetForAddToUserDto betForAddTo
```